# how to insert default value in table

Tags: mysql, sql, default-value

[image: On left side there is my queries and on right side it is an output given after completion of every query]

I've set default 'UNDECIDED' but it still shows me null. Please show me the correct way.
Thank you!!

Comment: Show is table definition and your INSERT.

Comment: please never post images only text is valid see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: @Jens can you pls rewrite here how?

Comment: replace with `major VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL DEFAULT...`

Comment: @Jens it's still showing the same answer

Comment: can you share you statements as text please

Comment: @Jens major VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'UNDECIDE'

Comment: @shashankagrawal please all the statements in your screenshot

Comment: I guess, the insert statemens doesn't work, becuase you miss to specify the student_id

Comment: Your insert statements doesn't work. You forget to specify the columns you want to insert

Comment: All your `INSERT` statements are missing the `student_id` column. That code can't be working with the table definition you show.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
INSERT INTO student (student_name) VALUES ('Test');
```

For more details you can read this tutorial:

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-basics/mysql-default/